# Rename numbered files while keeping text

Tags: regular-expression, rename

I am trying to rename a set of files. The files have this form

`frame\[d]+_object.bin`

I have files numberes from 1 to 1500, and I want to rename only the ones between 100 and 199

I have tried the following `rename` command

`rename -n 's/frame1[\d]{2}_/sprintf("%05d", $&)/e' *.bin`

adapting other command I was using for other purposes, but the output is

```
frame198_simobject0.bin -> 00000simobject0.bin
frame199_simobject0.bin -> 00000simobject0.bin
```

I don't really understand how the substitution rule for the command is working, so some help here would be very useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$&` is the whole matched string - including the leading `frame` and trailing `_`. Since this is non-numeric, the attempt to format it according to `%05d` fails.

You probably want something like `s/frame(1\d{2})_/sprintf("frame%05d_", $1)/e`

ex.

```
$ rename -n 's/frame(1\d{2})_/sprintf("frame%05d_", $1)/e' *.bin
rename(frame198_simobject0.bin, frame00198_simobject0.bin)
rename(frame199_simobject0.bin, frame00199_simobject0.bin)
```

Note that you don't need character range brackets `[...]` around the `\d`.

Comment: thanks, this works like a charm. What does the $1 means?

Comment: @jjcasmar `$1` is a reference to the first *capture group* i.e. the text matching `(1\d{2})`. See for example [Use Parentheses for Grouping and Capturing](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)

Comment: thank you very much!

Comment: @jjcasmar If one of the answers solved your issue, please take a moment to [accept it](//$$SITEURL/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on [the checkmark on the left](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/203101). That will mark the question as answered and is the way that thanks are conveyed on the Stack Exchange sites.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to only rename a susbset of the files, a simple solution is to only pass *those* files to `rename`. So, instead of using `*bin`, use [brace expansion](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_04.html), to only pick up files with the right names:

```
rename -n 's/frame(\d+)_/sprintf("%05d", $1)/e'  frame{100..199}_simobject0.bin
```

Comment: I didnt even know this. What I was trying was to rename to then mv the files to a different folder. Now I know I can just mv that subset. I vote up this solution, but I must accept the previous one

Comment: @jjcasmar oh, yes, please do. This is just a minor addition, steeldriver gave the solution.